# How to 'cd' to Ubuntu external drive?

Tags: ubuntu, external-hard-drive, navigation

I have an external drive connected to my Ubuntu system.

I can use my file browser (Dolphin) to access the files on the drive.

From my home directory I don't know how to 'cd' to the drive.

Comment: Do you use a shell or a GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on where the drive is mounted to. In dolphin you should be able so see the full path. In terminal use that path after the `cd` command.

example:

```
cd /media/external
```

Comment: Thanks, John T. When you say you need a coop position, do you mean "internship"? Would you consider working in the US? Hard to imagine someone with your chops would have any problems finding something near where you live.

Comment: I only need a 4 month or 8 month position, but I'd consider the US if I had accomodations :)

Comment: You could probably find a 6-month contract in a major city that pays well enough that you could afford a cheap room (by the week or month) from Craigslist if the goal is to save as much as possible. If so, the major recruiting agencies like kforce, teksystems, manpower, etc might be the way to go. Free accomodation is a tall order though :)

Comment: Oh I'm definitely assuming to pay. It's just the problem of getting a placement without a lot of on-the-job IT experience.

Comment: Yes, that's tricky but showing off personal projects, tech blog, open-source contributions, stackoverflow, all can help, especially if you target smaller companies rather than big corporate environments where they will be stricter about on-the-job experience.